# can't select radio buttons on multiple forms

Tags: python, html, css, flask, sass

So, I have multiple jobs in view with "Report" modal. in that modal there is a form with reasons to report. The problem is that radio button highlights only in first form. if I open report for fifth job it will change first job report modal and there will be no button highlight, but if you open modal of first job, its highlight. I made sure to change name= attribute of every group, so I don't understand why it's happening

```html
<!-- Modal report posting -->
<div class="modal" id="{{post.id}}-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="validate-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Report</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>

      </div>
      {{post.id}}
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="" class="report_job_form" method="post" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="crf-protect" id="crf-protect" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
          <div class="report-element">
            <div class="report-category hoverable">
              <p>
                <label for="fkj">
                    <input type="radio" id="fkj" name="report{{post.Position}}_value" value="Fake Job">
                    <span>Fake Job</span>
                </label>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="report-category hoverable">
              <p>
                <label for="disc-3">
                    <input type="radio" id="disc-3" name="report{{post.Position}}_value" value="Discrimination">
                    <span>Discrimination</span>
                </label>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="report-category hoverable">
              <p>
                <label for="advert">
                    <input type="radio" id="advert" name="report{{post.Position}}_value" value="Advertisement">
                    <span>Advertisement</span>
                </label>
              </p>

            </div>

            <div class="report-category hoverable">
              <p>
                <label for="other-2">
                    <input type="radio" id="other-2" name="report{{post.Position}}_value" value="Other">
                    <span>Other</span>
                </label>
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <textarea id="textarea7" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="120" name="details"></textarea>
            <label for="textarea2">More Details</label>
          </div>
          <input type="hidden" name="user-ident" id="user-ident" value="{{current_user.id}}" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" name="post-ident" id="post-ident" value="{{post.id}}" readonly>
          <input class="btn report-submit" type="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: P.S. sorry for indentation :)

Comment: maybe every modal should have unique ID to open correct modal

Comment: @furas Looks like they do: `<div class="modal" id="{{post.id}}-1"`

Comment: How are you highlighting the radio buttons? The radio buttons have IDs, are they unique across all the modals?

Comment: @Barmar I mean, when you click radio button it turns blue, when I click every radio button form, in any form except 1, it does nothing...but if you open 1 form modal its shows checked button that you clicked in last form

Comment: Please post a [mre] that has multiple forms so we can see this happening. To keep it minimal, remove everything unrelated to the radio buttons.

Comment: @furas  it opens correct form, and it submits right form, the only think is missing that radio button